# Is there a free web based tool to view the database schema and its properties

Tags: database-schema

Is there a free web based tool (I prefer Microsoft because I have an MSDN account) to view the database schema and its properties? I'm currently using Visio but I dont know if it's possible in Visio to do the following:

1. View the database schema that I will upload in a Sharepoint workspace.
2. If I click the name of the Database table, it will either pop up a small window with its database properties and column description or another window will pop up with its database properties and column description.

For example I have a Schema table interface composed of a profile and time tables.

THESE ARE JUST EXAMPLES.

```
ProfileDim table                  

Profile ID number(10)
FirstName  varchar (20)        
MiddleName varchar (20)
LastName   varchar (20)           TimeDim Table
DateHired  datetime---------------EmployeeStartDate  datetime,  
                                  Date_Name          nvarchar(50),       
                                  Year               datetime,
```

If I click the name "TimeDim" it will take me to another page where I can see the database properties written below and the description of each column. I prefer not to use MS excel or word. I want a tool that I could edit, delete in case I want to add another column, change the data type and change the name etc.

```
TimeDim table       

COLUMN NAME           DATA TYPE       ALLOW NULLS   DESCRIPTION
EmployeeStartDate     datetime,       Unchecked     "START DATE OF THE EMPLOYEE"
Date_Name             nvarchar(50),   Checked       "CURRENT DATE NAME"
Year                  datetime,       Checked       "NAME OF THE CURRENT YEAR"
```

Comment: what database software are you using?

Answer (score 1):

There are several tools that generate your database documentation to for example html. I don't know online tools but the generated docs can be placed online ofcourse. They are not free but you can use them in the evaluation perio to generate the database documentation

[toad data modeler](http://www.quest.com/toad-data-modeler/)

[dbdesc](http://www.dbdesc.com/)

[dezign for databases](http://www.datanamic.com/dezign/)

Answer (score 0):

For Microsoft DB servers, you can use SQL Server Management Studio Express.
The DB schema management tool depends on which database software you are using. There are different tools to MySQL, PostgreSQL, Microsoft SQL Server, etc...

Comment: Hi Patrick and Thaddeus,I'm using SSMS and BIDS/Visual Studio

Comment: @BeauAlagan What database are you using?